# Quickest way to return list of Strings by using wildcard from collection in Java

Tags: java, search, collections

I have set of 100000 String. And for example I want to get all strings starting with "JO" from that set. What would be the best solution for that?

I was thinking [Aho-Corasick but the implementation I have](https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/java/index.html) does not support wild cards.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but what's wrong with looping and doing `str.matches(somePattern)`?

Comment: Are you always going to be looking for strings of the form "xyz*", or do you also want to look for strings of the form "x*y" etc?

Comment: @aioobe, your suggestion is O(n) for each lookup, and also incurs possibly unnecessary memory use to return results.

Comment: @Mat you don't want to go there. Java Strings are unicode-based. Matching bytes will be hell

Comment: @aioobe `str.matches(somePattern)` will compile the same pattern over and over again, thousands of times

Comment: If you compare them more than once, it could be faster to sort them once, and then to do a binary search.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want all the strings starting with a sequence you can add all the String into a NavigableSet like TreeSet and get the `subSet(text, text+'\uFFFF')` will give you all the entries starting with `text`  This lookup is O(log n)

---

If you want all the Strings with end with a sequence, you can do a similar thing, except you have to reverse the String.  In this case a TreeMap from reversed String to forward String would be a better structure.

If you want "x*z" you can do a search with the first set and take a union with the values of the Map.

if you want contains "*x*", you can use a Navigable<String, Set<String>> where the key is each String starting from the first, second, third char etc The value is a Set as you can get duplicates. You can do a search like the starts with structure.

Comment: That's elegant! But if you don't already have the `TreeSet`, filling it will be `O(n log n)`, when just simply searching an `ArrayList` is `O(n)`

Comment: Right. The topic states that he has a "collection". Hopefully he is able to choose this collection himself.

Comment: @aioobe, I had hoped he has a Set already which can be easily changed to a TreeSet or ConcurrentSkipListSet if concurrency is required.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a custom matcher class that does the matching without regular expressions (it only uses regex in the constructor, to put it more precisely) and supports wildcard matching:

```
public class WildCardMatcher {
    private Iterable<String> patternParts;
    private boolean openStart;
    private boolean openEnd;

    public WildCardMatcher(final String pattern) {
        final List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>(
                                     Arrays.asList(pattern.split("\\*")));
        while (tmpList.remove("")) { /* remove empty Strings */ }
        // these last two lines can be made a lot simpler using a Guava Joiner
        if (tmpList.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid pattern");
        patternParts = tmpList;
        openStart = pattern.startsWith("*");
        openEnd = pattern.endsWith("*");
    }

    public boolean matches(final String item) {
        int index = -1;
        int nextIndex = -1;
        final Iterator<String> it = patternParts.iterator();
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            String part = it.next();
            index = item.indexOf(part);
            if (index < 0 || (index > 0 && !openStart))
                return false;
            nextIndex = index + part.length();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                part = it.next();
                index = item.indexOf(part, nextIndex);
                if (index < 0)
                    return false;
                nextIndex = index + part.length();
            }
            if (nextIndex < item.length())
                return openEnd;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    testMatch("foo*bar", "foobar", "foo123bar", "foo*bar", "foobarandsomethingelse");
    testMatch("*.*", "somefile.doc", "somefile", ".doc", "somefile.");
    testMatch("pe*", "peter", "antipeter");
}

private static void testMatch(final String pattern, final String... words) {
    final WildCardMatcher matcher = new WildCardMatcher(pattern);
    for (final String word : words) {
        System.out.println("Pattern " + pattern + " matches word '"
                          + word + "': " + matcher.matches(word));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Pattern foo*bar matches word 'foobar': true
Pattern foo*bar matches word 'foo123bar': true
Pattern foo*bar matches word 'foo*bar': true
Pattern foo*bar matches word 'foobarandsomethingelse': false
Pattern *.* matches word 'somefile.doc': true
Pattern *.* matches word 'somefile': false
Pattern *.* matches word '.doc': true
Pattern *.* matches word 'somefile.': true
Pattern pe* matches word 'peter': true
Pattern pe* matches word 'antipeter': false
```

While this is far from being production-ready, it should be fast enough and it supports multiple wild cards (including in the first and last place). But of course if your wildcards are only at the end, use Peter's answer (+1).

Comment: is it possible to get a \W mixed into your solution without being forced to use regex?