# Match a string String against large list of regexps, performance, in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, list

I have following:

```
private static List<Pattern> pats;
```

This list contains around 90 patterns that is instantiated before iteration. The patterns are complex, like:

```
System.out.println("pat: " + pats.get(0).toString());

// pat: \bsingle1\b|\bsingle2\b|(?=.*\bcombo1\b)(?=.*\bcombo2\b)|\bsingle3\b|\bwild.*card\b ...
```

Some of the patterns contains around 40-50 single words or combination of words, as the regex above shows. The words can contain wildcards.

Now, I have a list of strings, sentences on around 30-60 characters each. I iterate through them and for every string in the list, I iterate them through the list of patterns and perform a `pattern.match("This is one of the strings in my list").find()` until I get a match, which I mark down and save somewhere else, then I break out of iteration through patterns and continue with the next string in the list.

This is a categorization job, so several strings can match on the same pattern.

My problem is that this of course takes a lot of execution time, I am looking for a more efficient way to solve this problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you may be looking for something like the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm).

Comment: You might try optimizing your regular expressions, heres a good post on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252194/regex-performance-optimization-tips-and-tricks

Comment: I don't think Aho-Corasick algoritm supports wildcards, but it was an interesting one and I found a few implementations, note to self for future needs.

Comment: When you find yourself generating monster regexes like this, it's a sure sign that you should not be using regexes.  They can be *part* of the solution, but trying to do everything in one regex is just making the job more difficult.

Comment: I had the same thought Alan, so I divided patterns up into a list of patterns instead and iterate through them (breaks if there's a hit). Didn't see the performance gain I was hoping for though. And of course, the classical problem, when not getting matches, that takes the most time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that solved my problem (to 90%) was to give up regex partially where `String.indexOf()` made more sense out of a performance perspective.

This post inspired me: [Quickest way to return list of Strings by using wildcard from collection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952553/quickest-way-to-return-list-of-strings-by-using-wildcard-from-collection-in-java)

I wrote my own implementation since the one in the link handles only full words, while I'm dealing with sentences.

It helped with wildcards "*" and pipes "hel(l|lo)" in the performance perspective, the former more than the latter.

Reason for this direction was several recommendations, and it improved performance by cutting down time on 200000 sentences from 1.5 hour down to 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You could also offload the regular expression in a dedicated service ? I believe that it could be faster (and perhaps safer) than giving up regexp partially ?

If your app is intended to run on multiple server, you may also gain performances by centralizing the computation cost.

Here is an example of such implementation via a REST api : http://www.rex-daemon.com/tutorial/more-advanced-queries/